# Recursively print Factorial values in decreasing order?

Tags: c++, recursion, factorial

Using C++ to figure out the factorial is straightforward enough. To print the values coming up (if factorial is 5) ... 1 * 2, * 3, * 4 * 5 also no problem - as I think I've done below.
But what I'm having a hard time doing is saying show me 5 * 4 then value * 3 then value * 2 etc. I want to  be able to print the data going down and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   

int factorial(int n);

int main()
{
   int number;

   cout << "Enter an integer value ";
   cin >> number;

   cout << "The factorial of " << number << " is ";
   cout << factorial(number) << endl;
}

int factorial(int n)
{
   if (n == 0)
      return 1;                    // Base case
   else
   {
      n = n * factorial(n - 1); // Recursive case
      cout << " going up" << n << " ";
      return n;
   }
}
```

There are a couple of other posts but I didn't find one asking the same thing. 
The desired results are: 20 60 120 
The current results are 1 2 6 24 120
Please advise. 
Thank you.

Comment: Move the `cout <<` one line upwards.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the results are you expect and the results you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Did the answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change where you are printing the value

```
else
   {
      n = n * factorial(n - 1); // Recursive case
      cout << " going up" << n << " ";
      return n;
   }
```

to

```
else
   {
      cout << " going down" << n << " ";    
      n = n * factorial(n - 1); // Recursive case
      return n;
   }
```

The above would print `5 4 3 2 1` but if you want something like

```
5 20 60 ...
```

Than you have to change the recursive definition a bit.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int factorial(int n,int temp);
int main()
{
   int number;

   cout << "Enter an integer value ";
   cin >> number;

   cout << "The factorial of " << number << " is ";
   cout << factorial(number,1) << endl;
}

int factorial(int n,int temp)
{
   if (n == 0)
      return temp;                    // Base case
   else
   {   
      cout << " going down" << n * temp << " ";
      factorial(n - 1,n*temp); // Recursive case
      //return n;
   }   
}
```

Comment: to your above statement to print the 5 4 3 2 1 I was able to do without issue. I wanted to print the 20 60 120. (what the actual multiplication of each set of values would be). I would like to exclude the 5 - we just want the multiplication of the values.

Comment: than you can start with different call like if you want for 5! than call factorial(n-1,n)